# How to setup and read appsettings when creating a project in Visual Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, appsettings, configurationmanager

I started using Visual Code instead of VS- Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to setup appSettings.config and reference the key values using Configuration Manager.

This line throws a Nullreference exception:

```
var applicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"].ToString();
```

I manually added the file appSettings.config when I created the console application. Here's the Folder structure:

[image]

Is there additional configuration needed?

Comment: There's no `appsettings.config` in .NET. In .NET Framework settings are stored in `app.config` and accessed through `ConfigurationManager` or `Properties.Settings`. The weekly typed AppSetting is a remnant of .NET Framework 1, way back in 2002. Newer versions use strongly typed `ApplicationSettings` that can be edited using a VS GUI designer, accessible through `Properties.Settings`.

Comment: .NET Core (which includes .NET 5 and later) doesn't use any of this. There isn't even a ConfigurationManager any more. They use a far more powerful and easier Configuration Middleware, with `appsettings.json` just one of the sources.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Code you're probably using .NET Core, in which case you *shouldn't* use ConfigurationManager at all. Libraries and NuGet packages work expect settings through the Configuration middleware.

Comment: Thank you all - renaming it app.config worked.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to rename appsettings.config to app.config.